# Why does my overlay normal distribution curve look different every time I execute the script

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

My code generate a different curve every time I execute it. The red line looks different everytime I execute it. Is it suppose to behave like this?

```
hist(y # depandant variable (CFR)
, main = "Histogram " # chart title
, xlab = "CFR",
ylab = "Frequency",
col = "#f0ffff",
breaks = 15,
freq = FALSE,
prob = TRUE,
xlim = c(0.0,2.5),
ylim = c(0.0,2.0)
)

lines(density(y, adjust=1.2),  col="blue", lwd=2) 

y_norm = rnorm(length(y), mean(y), sd(y)); 

lines(density(y_norm, adjust=1.2),  col="red", lwd=2) 

grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL,
     lty = 1, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
```

[image: execution 1]

[image]

Comment: Yes, because you're sampling random points from the specified distribution using `rnorm()`. See also `?rnorm`

Comment: voting to close as a typo, because this is expected behaviour of a random number generator

Comment: how do I fix this? I want to overlay a fixed normal distribution curve?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it suppose to behave like this?

Yes, it is supposed to behave like this. If you want it to be the same each time, then also execute `set.seed(1)` (it doesn't have to be 1, but it does have the be the same each time if you want the red curve to be the same).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the density function, `dnorm()`. I show it to you in `curve()`:

```
hist(airquality$Temp, freq=F)
lines(density(airquality$Temp), col=2)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(airquality$Temp), sd(airquality$Temp)), add=T, col=4)
legend("topleft", c('empirical', 'theoretical'), lwd=1, col=c(2, 4), cex=.8)
```

[image]